# VS Code C# language server fails at startup "Client cound (!sic) not connect to server via named pipe"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Starting VS Code with a newly created C# console app leads to the following output and error:

[image]

There is a typo in the error message "cound" instead of "could", here is the corresponding source from the language server:

```
// Wait for the server to send back the name of the pipe to connect to.
// If it takes too long it will timeout and throw an error.
const pipeConnectionInfo = await Promise.race([namedPipeConnectionPromise, timeout]);

if (pipeConnectionInfo === undefined) 
{
    throw new Error('Timeout. Named pipe information not received from server.');
}

const socketPromise = new Promise<net.Socket>((resolve) => {
        _channel.appendLine('attempting to connect client to server...');
        const socket = net.createConnection(pipeConnectionInfo.pipeName, () => {
            _channel.appendLine('client has connected to server');
            resolve(socket);
        });
});

// Wait for the client to connect to the named pipe.
// If it takes too long it will timeout and throw an error.
const socket = await Promise.race([socketPromise, timeout]);

if (socket === undefined) 
{
    throw new Error('Timeout. Client could not connect to server via named pipe: ' + pipeConnectionInfo.pipeName);
}
```

Can anyone help me what's going wrong here?

Comment: You might report to Microsoft https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues No possible for a discussion here without accessing your machine.

Comment: If you found a problem in the C# language server, post an issue in the Github repo. StackOverflow users can't help you

Comment: There's a github issue created about it, look it: https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6842

Comment: There's a new prerelease version (2.19.13). Could you please switch to this version and try again?